# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in Ubuntu

Tags: python

I am just beginning with my code and have this in python

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from numpy.linalg import inv
import os
coeficientes_objetivo=[]
f1 = open('/home/david/Escritorio/objetivo.txt','r')
```

Although I have specified the path, this error continues to appear. I use Ubuntu.

[image: Click here to see the output of the terminal]

Comment: are you sure the file exists and is spelled correctly? Maybe add a `ls -l` output which proves it

Comment: Also can you show the output of `pwd`?

Comment: Yes, it exists, I am asking this question because I have searched in all sites and I don't seem to find and answer @Japu_D_Cret I am not that useless

Comment: @math4everyone sorry for being so direct, but since so little information​ was given it was necessary to ask. Not meant to belittle you, just you making it easier for us to help you

Comment: That is pure ascii text, but it may be utf-8 with non-ascii chars in the actual filename. They look similar but if you have accented characters for instance, it isn't the same.

Comment: In the objetivo directory, do `pwd objetivo.txt` then copy/paste that here. Then we'll know.

Comment: @math4everyone Could you [edit] the question to prove the file does exist where you say it does, then?

Comment: oops, typed that wrong... `pwd;ls objetivo.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal -> change directory to the objectivo.txt -> `pwd objectivo.txt`

You will get the correct path for the file

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the file in python:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from numpy.linalg import inv
import os
import sys
coeficientes_objetivo=[]
my_file = '/home/david/Escritorio/objetivo.txt'
if not os.path.exists(my_file):
    print("File path does not exist.")
    sys.exit()

if not os.path.isfile(my_file):
    print("File path is not a file.")
    sys.exit()

f1 = open(my_file,'r')
```